# Is the process $e^+e^- \to 2\eta_c$ possible for $L=0$?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, standard-model, quarks, parity

For the following 
$$e^+ e^- \to \eta_c \eta_c$$
I think it violates parity conservation so it can't happen, but is there any other reason as to why it can't take place? Or is it actually possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process could in general take place. A sample diagram is:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

With regards to Parity: Assuming the electron-positron pair don't have any angular momentum, the initial Parity is $-1$. Assuming the $\eta_C\eta_C$ pair don't have any angular momentum, their Parity is $+1$. Thus in this case the reaction cannot occur. If we assume the electron-positron don't have orbital angular momentum, then mesons can only be emitted in excited states.

However, in the above we assumed that the particle mediating the interaction is a photon. The $Z$ boson does not conserve Parity and at high energies (the $Z$ boson is heavy and can't be made at low energies) one can also find ground state mesons.

Comment: I was going by the assumption that it was an electromagnetic interaction as in linear colliders, but that is a good point about the Z boson. CP violation can occur with the weak interaction so the process would be allowed. Thanks for the informative answer!